# sharing data between multiple processes using NSUserDefault

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

I'd like to share data between objective-c compiled process and terminal. both running by the same user.

From the objC code I wrote some value under domain `a.b.c`:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"a.b.c"];
[defaults setObject:@"fffff" forKey:@"bbbbb"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This process is in fact installer plugin that runs from installer.app and has the following entitlements (no sandbox) :

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app
-->
Executable=/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.tcc.allow-prompting</key>
    <array>
        <string>kTCCServiceAll</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And expected this value to be visible from the terminal using `defaults read`. But unfortunately, it doesn't shown up even though both processes are running under the same user.

Here's the output from terminal :

```
defaults read a.b.c
2020-09-15 14:56:58.245 defaults[23380:360050] 
Domain a.b.c does not exist
```

Any Idea what I'm missing here ?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the entire Terminal command?

Comment: I've added the defaults exact command and response. notice however, that if I run another instance of the same process that wrote the value "fffff", it can trace this value, but other processes probably cannot

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: @Willeke, updated the question with the entitlements. the application which write the data is not sandboxed (see entitlements above).

Answer (score 1):

I am a novice, I don't know what you mean by "processes".

(Perhaps two programs, Xcode executes one, terminal executes one).

But I know that "NSUserdefaults" stores data in a sandbox.

There is no sandbox for terminal programs, and the sandbox for each program is separate.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know that in macOS `NSUserDefaults` is per user if I write to specific domain, and not per application.